# Data.gov: Is the API Version 3 down completely?

Tags: api, data.gov

We've been getting errors from data.gov that multiple API calls are down, anyone know what the ETA is for getting it back up?

Comment: Can you give an example of what's not working for you? http://catalog.data.gov/api/3/action/package_search works for me.

Answer (score 5):

Rebecca, from the Data.gov team here. Following up on this, to our knowledge the Data.gov CKAN API hasn't been down. Can you provide more details on the issues you were having?

If helpful in constructing your query parameters, here is documentation on the CKAN API: http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/api/index.html#making-an-api-request

Also, we are working to provide additional documentation specific to the Data.gov CKAN API, you can follow that progress or weigh in here: https://github.com/GSA/data.gov/issues/180

I hope that helps!